# Can dbt show data dependency to non dbt table?

Tags: dbt

I'm am a big fan of the data lineage graph generated by `dbt`.

[image]

However, this only shows the relationships between tables & views created by `dbt`. Is there a way to show the dependencies to "original" tables in the database?

Say, if my `dbt` model creates a view of called `open_orders` as

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status='Open'
```

I'd like to have the data lineage graph show that `open_orders` depends on `orders`.

Comment: I guess you could use DBT [Sources](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources) for that, right? If you create a source of your `orders` table, it will appear in the data lineage

Comment: Yes. If you put it as an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DBT Sources](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources) for that. If you create a source of your `orders` table, it will appear in the data lineage.